# bytes to Image Conversion in java

Tags: java, arrays, javax.imageio

I am trying to convert Image to Byte Array and save it in database. Image to Byte Conversion and bytes to Image Conversion using ImageIO Method works completely fine before saving it into database. But when i retrieve bytes from Database ImageIO returns null.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(picturePath);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(picturePath));
BufferedImage img = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, 124, 133, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);

ByteArrayOutputStream ByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", ByteStream);
ByteStream.flush();

byte[] imageBytes = ByteStream.toByteArray();
ByteStream.close();

PersonImage = imageBytes;

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(PersonImage);
BufferedImage ImageForBox = ImageIO.read((InputStream)byteArrayInputStream);            
PersonImageBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon((Image)ImageForBox));
```

Above code is what I do before saving picture bytes in DB. I resize the Image then convert it into bytes and then convert other way around and show it in JLabel, it works fine. But when I retrieve bytes from database and use the same code i.e.

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(PersonImage); // PersonImage are bytes from dB.
BufferedImage ImageForBox = ImageIO.read((InputStream)byteArrayInputStream);            
PersonImageBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon((Image)ImageForBox));
```

In this case ImageIO returns null. Please help.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, but I don't see where you sent it to the database.  I assume that that's the issue.

Comment: @SteveP. Thanks alot but I figured it out moments after posting this question. The issue was in receiving bytes from DB. I was getting one extra byte in start of array which was the reason for ImageIO to not detect the format and thats why it was not able to match it with the listed formats. Hence ImageIO was returning NULL. After adjusting the byte array everything went just fine.

Comment: I knew it had to have something to do with what's not here, as it all looks properly coded.  Do you know why the extra byte is present?

Comment: Not Yet Steve, I am working on it. Checking both Client / Server sides, sending / receiving methods.